# Can enemies frozen by something other than Frost Nova trigger Shatter when killed?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

[Frost Nova's Shatter rune](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/frost-nova) claims that "*A frozen enemy that is killed has a 50% chance of releasing another Frost Nova.*" Meanwhile, [Ice Armor](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/ice-armor) causes melee attackers to be chilled or frozen for 2 seconds, and a rune for [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/blizzard) can freeze enemies.

If an enemy is frozen by something besides Frost Nova and killed while I have Shatter equipped, can it release a Frost Nova?

Comment: "releasing **another** frost nova" gives it away.

Comment: I've expanded the scope of this a bit, given that there's a few different freezes available and the answer seems to be the same for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing<sup>1</sup> both the freeze effect from [Ice Armor](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/ice-armor) and from [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/blizzard), I've discovered that it is not possible to generate a Frost Nova when killing a frozen enemy unless that enemy was frozen with Frost Nova.

<sub>1: Because of the 50% chance of a Frost Nova on Shatter, it is statistically possible that in my testing I did not see the effect even though it could still be achieved. However, I tested roughly twenty freezings with each methodology, so that is *extraordinarily* unlikely.</sub>